# Weird output with ragged2e and tikzposter class

Tags: tikzposter, bugs, ragged2e

I was making a tikzposter and noticed a strange `1=1` output somewhere on the output pdf. Trying to debug what was the cause of this result, I found out that the following simple working example, reproduces the error.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\title{hello}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no 1=1 but the terminal shows `Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!`  so something is wrong somewhere

Comment: I get that even without ragged2e

Comment: What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: @egreg Output of `tex --version` gives me `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`. Same bug happens also on Fedora 36 (I am not in the Fedora 36 right now, so I can't provide the version, I will do it asap though).

Comment: @adosar With TL 2019 I get a shift to the right, but not `1=1`. Anyway, `tikzposter` is quite buggy, if I remember correctly.